# Why does using a function give me an error?

Tags: c++

If a variable is passed in directly, it works just fine, but when I use a function that just returns the variable, it stops working. Why does this happen?

```
struct Edge {
    Point ap() const { return set[a]; }

    Point *set;
    int a;
}

function f(Point &p) {}

Edge e;

f(e.ap()); // Error: No matching function call to 'f'
f(e.set[e.a]); // Works fine

Point p = e.ap();
f(p); // Works fine
```

Comment: -1 for "stops working" without any attempt to describe the error or go into any kind of detail. As well as for the not very useful question title.

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually, it says "Error: No matching function call to 'f'" next to where the error occurs.

Comment: Which is almost guaranteed not to be the full error message, nor did you make any attempt to understand the actual error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Point ap() const { ... }
```

`ap` returns by value, and since you aren't storing the function call anywhere, doing this:

```
 f(e.ap());
```

returns a temporary object to `f`, which can't bind to a `Point&` type.

You have a number of options, you can...

- Have `Point::ap` return by const reference, that is

  ```
   Point const& ap() { ... }
  ```
- Make `f` take its argument by `const&`, by value, or through an rvalue-reference `Point&&`
- Store the result of the function call in a variable:

  ```
   Point p = e.ap();
   f(p);
  ```

Comment: Is there any way to have the function return by reference?

Comment: @stas Change the return type to `Point&` in the `ap` function.

Comment: @stas Yes. Since you would be returning a reference to a member of `Edge` you can do it safely. Use `const Point& ap() const {...}`

Comment: Oh I thought I had already tried that for some reason and it didn't work, but I must have mixed something up

Comment: @stas Have you made any changes? Is your program working now?

Answer (score 2):

The `Point` returned by `ap` is a temporary. In order to pass a temporary as an argument the function needs to take the argument by value, `const` reference, or rvalue reference.

```
void function f(Point p) {}         // By value
void function f(const Point& p) {}  // By const reference
void function f(Point &&p) {}       // By rvalue reference
```